# Linear Solve Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to use mathematica to solve the following system of equation, but I can not for the life of me get it to work.  I have the following:

```
Stiffness = ((Y*A)/L )*{{1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 2, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 
 2, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}} // MatrixForm

Displacements = {{0}, {a}, {b}, {0}} // MatrixForm

Force = {{x}, {(7*L^3 )/162}, {(10*L^3)/81}, {y}} // MatrixForm
```

I need to solve:

```
Stiffness * Displacements = Force
```

When I use LinearSolve it just spits back the input command.  I need to solve for a, b, x, and y.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn’t `Displacements = {{0}, {a}, {b}, {0}}` be `Displacements = {0, a, b, 0}`? The same change should apply for `Force`, IMO. How do you use the [LinearSolve function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html)?

Comment: What about `solution = Solve[Thread[Stiffness . Displacements == Force], {a, b, x, y}]`? See the “Properties & Relations” part of LinearSolve documentation. [See in WolframAlpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[Thread[%28%28Y*A%29%2FL+%29*{{1%2C+-1%2C+0%2C+0}%2C+{-1%2C+2%2C+-1%2C+0}%2C+{0%2C+-1%2C+++2%2C+-1}%2C+{0%2C+0%2C+-1%2C+1}}+.+{{0}%2C+{a}%2C+{b}%2C+{0}}+%3D%3D+{{x}%2C+{%287*L^3+%29%2F162}%2C+{%2810*L^3%29%2F81}%2C+{y}}]%2C+{a%2C+b%2C+x%2C+y}])

Comment: I tried changing the displacements and force matrices as you recommended, and I got the same result.  I have tried    `LinearSolve[Stiffness, Force]`, but was not sure of what the correct way of solving this problem would be.

Comment: Using `solution = Solve[Thread[Stiffness . Displacements == Force], {a, b, x, y}]` yields "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve"

Comment: In WA it does not work, too. Don’t know the reason. Hope someone else helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In[1]:= Stiffness = ((Y*A)/L)*{{1,-1,0,0},{-1,2,-1,0},{0,-1,2,-1},{0,0,-1,1}};
Displacements = {0, a, b, 0};
Force = {x, (7*L^3)/162, (10*L^3)/81, y};
Solve[Stiffness.Displacements == Force, {x, y, a, b}]

Out[4]= {{x-> -((17 L^3)/243), y-> -((47 L^3)/486), a->(17 L^4)/(243 A Y), b->(47 L^4)/(486 A Y)}}
```

Don't use //MatrixForm unless you just want something pretty to look at, BUT which you cannot then use for any subsequent calculations.

Don't use * when you want vector or matrix multiply, use .

Don't think you can get column vectors by wrapping every element inside another layer of {}

If Solve isn't working for a matrix problem then the first thing to look at is the matrix problem without Solve so you can see if your dimensions all match up.